# Comparing results of model training in keras tensorflow backend

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

I trained 6000 images on two cnn networks and they appear to be giving me similar results. The model is trained for binary classification the diffrence between the two models is in the dense layers Model A has following dense layer config

```
fc1 (Dense)                  (None, 512)               12845568  
_________________________________________________________________
fc2 (Dense)                  (None, 256)               131328    
_________________________________________________________________
output (Dense)               (None, 2)                 514
```

and result

```
Train on 4800 samples, validate on 1200 samples
Epoch 1/30
4800/4800 [===] - 98s - loss: 0.7923 - acc: 0.6865 - val_loss: 0.4599 - val_acc: 0.7858

Epoch 2/30
4800/4800 [===] - 80s - loss: 0.4263 - acc: 0.7996 - val_loss: 0.5913 - val_acc: 0.6350

Epoch 3/30
4800/4800 [===] - 80s - loss: 0.3912 - acc: 0.8133 - val_loss: 0.3199 - val_acc: 0.8625

Epoch 4/30
4800/4800 [===] - 80s - loss: 0.3562 - acc: 0.8402 - val_loss: 0.3086 - val_acc: 0.8708

Epoch 5/30
4800/4800 [===] - 80s - loss: 0.3251 - acc: 0.8558 - val_loss: 0.2784 - val_acc: 0.8817

Epoch 6/30
4800/4800 [===] - 80s - loss: 0.3150 - acc: 0.8631 - val_loss: 0.2792 - val_acc: 0.8817

Epoch 7/30
4800/4800 [===] - 80s - loss: 0.2997 - acc: 0.8692 - val_loss: 0.3615 - val_acc: 0.8342

Epoch 8/30
4800/4800 [===] - 80s - loss: 0.2990 - acc: 0.8662 - val_loss: 0.2630 - val_acc: 0.8908

Epoch 9/30
4800/4800 [===] - 80s - loss: 0.2594 - acc: 0.8867 - val_loss: 0.3102 - val_acc: 0.8700

Epoch 10/30
4800/4800 [===] - 80s - loss: 0.2846 - acc: 0.8785 - val_loss: 0.4234 - val_acc: 0.7842

Epoch 11/30
4800/4800 [===] - 80s - loss: 0.2510 - acc: 0.8969 - val_loss: 0.2952 - val_acc: 0.8742

Epoch 12/30
4800/4800 [===] - 80s - loss: 0.2288 - acc: 0.9090 - val_loss: 0.2680 - val_acc: 0.8858

Epoch 13/30
4800/4800 [===] - 80s - loss: 0.2277 - acc: 0.9044 - val_loss: 0.3745 - val_acc: 0.8600

Epoch 14/30
4800/4800 [===] - 80s - loss: 0.2659 - acc: 0.8873 - val_loss: 0.2438 - val_acc: 0.9025

Epoch 15/30
4800/4800 [===] - 80s - loss: 0.2101 - acc: 0.9133 - val_loss: 0.3176 - val_acc: 0.8667

Epoch 16/30
4800/4800 [===] - 80s - loss: 0.2094 - acc: 0.9146 - val_loss: 0.2763 - val_acc: 0.8875

Epoch 17/30
4800/4800 [===] - 80s - loss: 0.2058 - acc: 0.9125 - val_loss: 0.2677 - val_acc: 0.8925

Epoch 18/30
4800/4800 [===] - 80s - loss: 0.1839 - acc: 0.9296 - val_loss: 0.2449 - val_acc: 0.9117

Epoch 19/30
4800/4800 [===] - 80s - loss: 0.1918 - acc: 0.9221 - val_loss: 0.2471 - val_acc: 0.8992

Epoch 20/30
4800/4800 [===] - 80s - loss: 0.2014 - acc: 0.9225 - val_loss: 0.2709 - val_acc: 0.8808

Epoch 21/30
4800/4800 [===] - 80s - loss: 0.1540 - acc: 0.9425 - val_loss: 0.2541 - val_acc: 0.8933

Epoch 22/30
4800/4800 [===] - 80s - loss: 0.1803 - acc: 0.9294 - val_loss: 0.2289 - val_acc: 0.9058

Epoch 23/30
4800/4800 [===] - 80s - loss: 0.1548 - acc: 0.9425 - val_loss: 0.2417 - val_acc: 0.9175

Epoch 24/30
4800/4800 [===] - 80s - loss: 0.1754 - acc: 0.9294 - val_loss: 0.4914 - val_acc: 0.8183

Epoch 25/30
4800/4800 [===] - 80s - loss: 0.1449 - acc: 0.9419 - val_loss: 0.2281 - val_acc: 0.9125

Epoch 26/30
4800/4800 [===] - 80s - loss: 0.1529 - acc: 0.9385 - val_loss: 0.2328 - val_acc: 0.9217

Epoch 27/30
4800/4800 [===] - 80s - loss: 0.1237 - acc: 0.9533 - val_loss: 0.2646 - val_acc: 0.9167

Epoch 28/30
4800/4800 [===] - 80s - loss: 0.1236 - acc: 0.9531 - val_loss: 0.2485 - val_acc: 0.9100

Epoch 29/30
4800/4800 [===] - 80s - loss: 0.1301 - acc: 0.9500 - val_loss: 0.2726 - val_acc: 0.9042

Epoch 30/30
4800/4800 [===] - 80s - loss: 0.1335 - acc: 0.9500 - val_loss: 0.2803 - val_acc: 0.9183

Training time: 2440.315860271454
1200/1200 [===] - 27s    
[INFO] loss=0.2803, accuracy: 91.8333%

=================================================================

Model B has following final dense layer config

fc1 (Dense)                  (None, 1024)              25691136  
_________________________________________________________________
fc2 (Dense)                  (None, 512)               524800    
_________________________________________________________________
output (Dense)               (None, 2)                 1026      


Result
Train on 4800 samples, validate on 1200 samples
Epoch 1/30
4800/4800 [===] - 87s - loss: 0.4743 - acc: 0.7708 - val_loss: 0.4073 - val_acc: 0.8233

Epoch 2/30
4800/4800 [===] - 87s - loss: 0.3732 - acc: 0.8263 - val_loss: 0.3359 - val_acc: 0.8525

Epoch 3/30
4800/4800 [===] - 87s - loss: 0.3383 - acc: 0.8500 - val_loss: 0.3017 - val_acc: 0.8658

Epoch 4/30
4800/4800 [===] - 87s - loss: 0.3094 - acc: 0.8637 - val_loss: 0.3024 - val_acc: 0.8683

Epoch 5/30
4800/4800 [===] - 87s - loss: 0.3036 - acc: 0.8669 - val_loss: 0.3848 - val_acc: 0.8058

Epoch 6/30
4800/4800 [===] - 87s - loss: 0.2848 - acc: 0.8802 - val_loss: 0.2730 - val_acc: 0.8883

Epoch 7/30
4800/4800 [===] - 87s - loss: 0.2630 - acc: 0.8877 - val_loss: 0.3234 - val_acc: 0.8667

Epoch 8/30
4800/4800 [===] - 87s - loss: 0.2491 - acc: 0.8952 - val_loss: 0.2758 - val_acc: 0.8933

Epoch 9/30
4800/4800 [===] - 87s - loss: 0.2484 - acc: 0.8992 - val_loss: 0.3271 - val_acc: 0.8467

Epoch 10/30
4800/4800 [===] - 87s - loss: 0.2427 - acc: 0.8992 - val_loss: 0.2743 - val_acc: 0.8808

Epoch 11/30
4800/4800 [===] - 87s - loss: 0.2346 - acc: 0.9017 - val_loss: 0.2379 - val_acc: 0.9008

Epoch 12/30
4800/4800 [===] - 87s - loss: 0.2250 - acc: 0.9108 - val_loss: 0.2432 - val_acc: 0.9017

Epoch 13/30
4800/4800 [===] - 87s - loss: 0.1993 - acc: 0.9221 - val_loss: 0.2892 - val_acc: 0.8858

Epoch 14/30
4800/4800 [===] - 87s - loss: 0.2148 - acc: 0.9125 - val_loss: 0.3201 - val_acc: 0.8842

Epoch 15/30
4800/4800 [===] - 87s - loss: 0.1823 - acc: 0.9287 - val_loss: 0.5481 - val_acc: 0.8133

Epoch 16/30
4800/4800 [===] - 87s - loss: 0.1873 - acc: 0.9281 - val_loss: 0.2449 - val_acc: 0.9092

Epoch 17/30
4800/4800 [===] - 87s - loss: 0.1622 - acc: 0.9392 - val_loss: 0.2373 - val_acc: 0.9092

Epoch 18/30
4800/4800 [===] - 87s - loss: 0.1782 - acc: 0.9304 - val_loss: 0.2856 - val_acc: 0.8725

Epoch 19/30
4800/4800 [===] - 87s - loss: 0.1632 - acc: 0.9369 - val_loss: 0.2518 - val_acc: 0.9067

Epoch 20/30
4800/4800 [===] - 87s - loss: 0.1577 - acc: 0.9381 - val_loss: 0.2629 - val_acc: 0.9050

Epoch 21/30
4800/4800 [===] - 87s - loss: 0.1395 - acc: 0.9481 - val_loss: 0.2278 - val_acc: 0.9133

Epoch 22/30
4800/4800 [===] - 87s - loss: 0.1422 - acc: 0.9444 - val_loss: 0.2232 - val_acc: 0.9158

Epoch 23/30
4800/4800 [===] - 87s - loss: 0.1436 - acc: 0.9448 - val_loss: 0.2862 - val_acc: 0.9042

Epoch 24/30
4800/4800 [===] - 87s - loss: 0.1402 - acc: 0.9448 - val_loss: 0.3186 - val_acc: 0.8842

Epoch 25/30
4800/4800 [===] - 86s - loss: 0.1261 - acc: 0.9542 - val_loss: 0.2762 - val_acc: 0.9092

Epoch 26/30
4800/4800 [===] - 86s - loss: 0.1143 - acc: 0.9529 - val_loss: 0.2442 - val_acc: 0.9125

Epoch 27/30
4800/4800 [===] - 86s - loss: 0.1141 - acc: 0.9565 - val_loss: 0.3128 - val_acc: 0.8658

Epoch 28/30
4800/4800 [===] - 86s - loss: 0.1092 - acc: 0.9606 - val_loss: 0.2669 - val_acc: 0.9092

Epoch 29/30
4800/4800 [===] - 86s - loss: 0.0939 - acc: 0.9642 - val_loss: 0.2535 - val_acc: 0.8975

Epoch 30/30
4800/4800 [===] - 86s - loss: 0.1098 - acc: 0.9615 - val_loss: 0.2594 - val_acc: 0.9008

Training time: 2615.465226173401
1200/1200 [==============================] - 30s    
[INFO] loss=0.2594, accuracy: 90.0833%
```

both models seem to give similar results.Is this a good result or is there any anomalies that I cant detect? Or is the model a good one?
Additional info Batch size 128,loss=categorical cross-entropy,optimizer-adadelta
Any suggestions for improvent is also appriciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The next steps I would consider are:

- What is happening to your training loss. This is can be a useful metric. If you see your training loss go to 100% try adding more regularization, such as L2 regularization.
- Is your convolutional network using residual layers and batch normalization? Those residual networks using batch norm seem to be state of the art in most cases right now.
- Test different numbers of filters in each convolutional layer. If you have too many filters you overfit if you have too few you underfit. There's a sweet spot in there and it makes a difference.
- Your batch size can affect your results as well, play with it, I've done extensive hyperparameter searches on small vs. large datasets and come up with widely different ideal batch sizes
- You might test the Adam optimizer. AdaDelta is solid as well though.
- Train a number of models, random initialization will produce slightly different end results. Using an ensemble of models will do better still.
- Randomly initializing with the Xavier Initializer may give you a small bump in accuracy (there's a different one for conv layers and fc layers).
- Lower your learning rate after validation error plateaus, this typically improves performance some each time you lower it.

There are always many things you can try. Start running experiments, train a few models with various values of some of these suggestions and see where you get improvements.